# Adding dots to the chart bar with matplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, addition, dot

I'm creating some bar charts for all the columns in my df, but I would like to add some dots up the bar the original image I generate with my code (at the end of the post) are this ones:

[image]

And this is what I want:

[image]

Is this possible to do it with Python? suggestions or help with the code please

```
for i in df.columns:
    #print(i)
    ii= df[i].value_counts()
    #dfclean[i].value_counts().plot(kind="bar", figsize=(15,7), color="#61d199", title=i)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
    myList = ii.items()
    myList = sorted(myList) # or myList for not sorted by results
    x, y = zip(*myList) 

    for index in range(len(x)):
        ax.text(x[index], y[index], y[index], size=13)

    #plt.bar(x, y, color=('black', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'cyan'))
    #plt.bar(x, y, color=('#22314A'))
    plt.bar(x, y, color=('#22314A', '#E35855', '#1293C4', '#FFFFFF', '#CFAB2B', '#008080', '#AE0E36'))
    
    #plt.bar(x, y, color=('#22314A', '#E35855', '#1293C4', '#FFFFFF', '#CFAB2B'), width=0.1)# Modify width
    plt.xlabel("Answers", fontsize=20)
    plt.ylabel('No. answers', fontsize=20)
    plt.title(i, fontsize=20)
    plt.xticks(rotation=45, fontsize=16)#change rotation
    plt.yticks(fontsize=16)#change rotation
    
    i = i.replace(" ", "_")
    i = i.replace("[", "_")
    i = i.replace("]", "_")
    i = i.replace("?", "_")
    i = i.replace("/", "_")
    i = i.replace(".", "_")
    i = i.replace(":", "_")
    #print(i)
    plt.style.use('seaborn')
    plt.savefig(f'{i}.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an ellipse to a graph, use Artist. See the [reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Ellipse.html#matplotlib.patches.Ellipse) for more information. Based on the [sample graph](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_colors.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-bar-colors-py) in the reference, the fill color and edge color are prepared and annotations and ellipses are added in a loop process.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

fruits = ['apple', 'blueberry', 'cherry', 'orange']
counts = [40, 100, 30, 55]
bar_labels = ['black', 'red', 'blue', 'sand']
bar_colors = ['#22314A', '#E35855', '#1293C4', '#CFAB2B']
edge_color = ['#22314A', '#E35855', '#1293C4', 'black']

rects1 = ax.bar(fruits, counts, label=bar_labels, color=bar_colors)

ax.set_ylabel('fruit supply')
ax.set_title('Fruit supply by kind and color')
ax.legend(title='Fruit color')
ax.bar_label(rects1, padding=2)
for s in ['top','bottom','right','left']:
    ax.spines[s].set_visible(False)
    
ax.set_xlabel("Answers", fontsize=20)
ax.set_ylabel('No. answers', fontsize=20)
ax.set_title('Action', fontsize=20)
ax.set_ylim([0,130])
plt.xticks(rotation=45, fontsize=16)
plt.yticks(fontsize=16)

offset = 15
for i,(cnt,c,e) in enumerate(zip(counts,bar_colors, edge_color)): 
    e = patches.Ellipse(xy=(i, cnt+offset), width=0.4, height=15, fc=c, ec=e)
    ax.text(i, cnt+offset, str(cnt), color='white', ha='center', va='center')
    ax.add_patch(e)

plt.style.use('seaborn-v0_8')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi it actually is awesome thanks but I had to modidy some line because I'm using Colab and I cannot use .bar_label that is recent for matplotlib 3.4.2 not available still in colab. But I need some help with the :
´ax.set_ylim([0,130])´ 
how can I make this automatic depending on the highest label for each colum?

Comment: I can deal with this by upgrading Colab's matplotlib, though. `!pip install -U matplotlib` Do you suffer from any other limitation, the reason I am extending the y-axis limitation is to display ellipses. `ax.set_ylim([0,130])`

Comment: I tried to upgrading but the last version that upgrades is 3.2.2.

Yeah I know about the limit but there is another way to obtain the highest number to use it as limit?

Comment: I upgraded with Colab and it is now matplotlib:3.5.3. Did you restart the runtime?

Comment: To upgrade by version, try the following. `!pip install -U matplotlib==3.5.3`

Comment: How can I restart the runrtime?

Comment: At the bottom of the log, there is a `RESTART RUNTIME` button, click on it and press OK.